# Numerical evaluation of InverseFunction

Tags: numerics, special-functions, inverse-function

I am considering the inverse of the function rho[r]. I have used the InverseFunction to find the inverse, given by ry which is a monotonically increasing function of its argument $y$. Now for $1<q<-0.4$, numerical evaluation of the InverseFunction works perfectly with $y=1000$.

```
 q = -0.4;
 b0 = 1.;
 rho[r_] := (2 b0)/(1 - q) Sqrt[1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (q - 2)/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)];
 ry = InverseFunction[rho[#] &];
 dry[y_] := D[ry[y], y];
 ry[1000]
```

But for values $q=-0.4,-0.5,-0.6\cdots$, the InverseFunction returns unevaluated for $y=1000$. I don't understand why this does not work for a particular range of $q$ values. Is this possibly a bug? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're running into numerical precision issues.  Try specifying q=-6/10 and b0=1 to force arbitrary precision arithmetic, then evaluate ry[1000]//N.  You can also, within limits, rationalize the input real data using Rationalize[myReal,10^-(k)] to invoke arbitrary precision.

Comment: I've already tried that long before I posted this question and it did not solve my problem. It's weird that my code doesn't work well with $q\leq-0.4$ though but works with $q=-0.3$.

Comment: With q=-4/10 and b=1, ry[1000]//N=999.066.  Which one is not working?

Comment: @ChromoRunge wow, this works for me! Thanks

Comment: @Dominic I don't know but your suggestion does not work in my 11.3 version.

Comment: I have ver 12.0.0.0.  Keep in mind the Hypergeometric function has a default branch-cut (1,inf) so maybe that is causing problems.

Comment: The value for the variable $q$ is constrained to be $1<q<-\infty$ though.

Comment: The quantity z=1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q) in your expression, for which the branch-cut is defined, gets closer and closer to 1 as r is increased.

Comment: @Dominic, what possible complications do I get?

Comment: Sorry.  Don't know.

Comment: Try using ``q = -.4`20`` and `b = 1`.